# Зачем нужен context в android?

Tags: java, android

Наткнулся в коде, при создании интента передается объект `context`. Зачем он нужен, не понимаю ? Если можно, максимально просто.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Context** – это объект, который предоставляет доступ к базовым функциям приложения: доступ к ресурсам, к файловой системе, вызов активности и т.д. `Activity` является подклассом `Context`, поэтому в коде мы можем использовать её как `ИмяАктивности.this` (напр. `MainActivity.this`), или укороченную запись `this`. Классы `Service`, `Application` и др. также работают с контекстом.

Доступ к контексту можно получить разными способами. Существуют такие методы как `getApplicationContext()`, `getContext()`, `getBaseContext()` или `this`, который упоминался выше, если используется в активности.

На первых порах не обязательно понимать, зачем он нужен. Достаточно помнить о методах, которые позволяют получить контекст и использовать их в случае необходимости, когда какой-нибудь метод или конструктор будет требовать объект Context в своих параметрах.

В свою очередь Context имеет свои методы, позволяющие получать доступ к ресурсам и другим объектам.

```
getAssets()
getResources()
getPackageManager()
getString()
getSharedPrefsFile()
```

Comment: ИмяАктивности.this  - это обращение к активности из ее внутреннего класса, а this - это обращение к активности из нее самой. То есть второе не является укороченной записью первого.
Классы Service, Application и др. не работают с контекстом, а являются его подклассами.

Comment: Дополню, что некорректно переводить термин Activity как "активность", потому что "активность" — это процесс, а Activity — это сущность (в контексте обсуждения компонента).