# SendBroadcast из класса или наилучший метод получения контекста

Tags: java, android

Есть некий класс в одном из методов которого требуется послать сообщение, используя sendBroadcast. Чтобы вызвать этот метод нужен контекст. Примерно так:

```
class Storage {
 void update(){
  ...
  sendBroadcast(intent);
 }
}
```

Вопрос в том, какой наиболее приемлемый метод получения контекста в классе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошу пример передачи контекста классу через конструктор

```
class FirstClass{

// Cсылка на контекст
private Context context;

//принимает контекст  в конструктуе
public YourTwoClass(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}
```

}

Или еще один пример с помощью него можно получить контекст "везде"

```
public class MyApplication extends Application { 

static Context context;

@Override
public onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  this.context = getApplicationContext() 
}

public static Context getApplicationContext() { return this.context; }
}
```

Не забудь добавить в `manifest` а то кинет ошибочку

```
  <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
    </application>
```

а вот и наш герой

```
 MyApplication.getContext();  //  получай любимый контекст)))
```

Comment: Второй пример не совсем понятен. Как в статическом методе getApplicationContext можно использовать this ?

Comment: при помощи this вы смотрите все доступные методы ссылки  класса"Обьекта".Советую попробовать код и во время написания вам станет более яснее

Comment: а если нет то вот вам ссылочка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495861/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-context-%D0%B2-android

Comment: Я чего-то не вижу? Студия мне так же говорит: **error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context**

Comment: кинте код у меня всё работает

Comment: package com.myapplication;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyApplication extends Application{
 private Context context;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(){
  super.onCreate();
  this.context = getApplicationContext();
        }

 public static Context getApplicationContext(){
  return this.context;
 }
}

Comment: @tilin, в коде ошибка. Переменная `Context context` должна быть статической

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это да, но тогда и this надо убирать в **this.context**

Comment: @elik наверное ваш первый вариант оптимальный и простой, спасибо.

Comment: Использование Context в static ведёт к утечке памяти